# Is Stack Overflow based off of a known Content Management System?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

What Content Management System is Stack Overflow based on, if any?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's its own 'CMS'; though it's a CMS very much customized towards 'Q&A' and Forum type sites.

[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) is based on the Stack Overflow codebase -- and not the other way around.

See [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/) for what Stack Overflow was built with.

Comment: I'm not sure you have edited enough in this entire question. ;)

Comment: @Troggy It's hard work, getting the `Strunk & White` badge.  Not to mention it's rather gratifying to edit things.  Just be glad I didn't put Cornify in your post. :-D