# What does stackoverflow use as a content management system?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is Stack Overflow based off of a known Content Management System?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27893/is-stack-overflow-based-off-of-a-known-content-management-system)
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Wordpress?

Or does it have its own?

Comment: Please tell me the guess was a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow is a custom solution, I really don't think it could be built on top of an existing CMS. It was programmed as a site for collaborative Q&A.

See [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Answer (score 1):

Yes!, **[Wordpress](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-admin/)**, but only on [Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com)

For stackoverflow itself see - [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)